# How to use spring form taglib in conjunction with maven?

Tags: forms, spring, servlets

I added spring-webmvc to my maven dependencies.
According to some page I found I need to use this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It works fine and I can see the jar file in my m2 local repository.

But my problem is that I'm getting an error in my JSP file that says "The tag handler class for "form:form" (org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag) was not found on the Java Build Path".

It obviously is looking for org.springframework.web.servlet BUT I thought adding spring-webmvc would fix it as mentioned is several search results I've read. Plus I've used "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" in my spring bean configuration XML so I know it's loading parts of the spring-webmvc.

I've looked at repo1.maven.org and mvnrepository.com and I never saw them mentioned org.springframework.web.servlet.

I then decided to add web.servlet according to the springsource page (http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.web.servlet&version=3.1.3.RELEASE)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I then get this error "Missing artifact org.springframework:org.springframework.web.servlet:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE".

I added springsource own repo (http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq) to my pom.xml but I get the same "missing artifact" message.

I guess I'm stuck and need your help. thanks :)

Not sure if this is relevant but I've included 3 XML config files. :)

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.flinders.staffdirectory.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" >
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 
  </beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.flinders.staff.directory</groupId>
  <artifactId>directory-maven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>directory-maven Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>directory-maven</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The class is in 3.1.3 spring-webmvc; are you using the right taglib declaration etc?

Comment: I'm using: <%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

Comment: Plus I've used the same .jsp file in a non-maven project. I've copy/paste all the JAR files in a lib folder and added them manually in the JAVA Build Path.

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE. I AM A DUMMY :/ Seems I forgot to pass a modelAttribute for the form

Comment: I don't see how that would cause that error, or how a tiles taglib is related to a spring form tag, but ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I forgot to pass a modelAttribute to my form:

```
return new ModelAndView("search/SearchForm", "search", new Search());
```

Comment: Maybe it took you hours to find a single bug because you can be easily lost with xml stuff, and debuggers doesn't work easily with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I normally put this page directive at the top of the file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

Which should make sure that the form taglib is being loaded in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the taglib directive as the first line in the file.

Comment: Please post an example of what you did to add some substance and value to your answer.